# Best CSS color wheel sites

Tags: css, colors, styling, color-scheme

What site(s) do you recommend for looking at complimentary colors for site design? It would also be beneficial to enter a hex or RGB value and have the color wheel spit back complimentary colors.

Most popular:

- [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/)

Others in alphabetical order:

- [4096 Color Wheel](http://www.ficml.org/jemimap/style/color/wheel.html)
- [Allprofitallfree - color-wheel2](http://allprofitallfree.com/color-wheel2.html)
- [Color Wheel v1.2 Javascript color scheme generator](http://design.geckotribe.com/colorwheel/)
- [Colorblender](http://colorblender.com)
- [Colorotate](http://colorotate.org/)
- [Colorsontheweb - colorwheel](http://colorsontheweb.com/colorwheel.asp)
- [Colorschemedesigner](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)
- [Colorschemer](http://colorschemer.com/)
- [Colourlovers](http://colourlovers.com/)
- [Colr](http://colr.org/)
- [hslpicker](http://hslpicker.com)
- [Visibone - colorlab](http://visibone.com/colorlab/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Adobe's Kuler - http://kuler.adobe.com/

is widely considered to be the best color palette selector out there, as it also lets you share color palettes other users have created. Sign in, click create, and you'll have options including "complementary" that give you a good starting point if you have one color in mind.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.colorschemer.com has an online color scheme gallery.

They also have a free desktop app called [ColorPix](http://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php):

[image: colorpix]
<sub>(source: [colorschemer.com](http://www.colorschemer.com/images/colorpix_screen.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I purchased their tool and works great!

Comment: Absolutely fantastic application! They also have an online colour schemer application at http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html.

Answer (score 7):

I love [colourlovers.com](http://colourlovers.com). It's a great community and a great idea, though it doesn't really "spit back" colors as you were looking for. The community that contributes to it provides ample complementary colors though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a huge fan of Color Scheme Designer...

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

From the [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/#!5342903/color-scheme-designer-is-a-diverse-palette-creator)...

> You can generate single monochromatic,
> complimentary, triad, tetrad,
> analogic, and accented analogic color
> palettes. You can simulate color-based
> vision disorders to see how your
> design colors will look—they even list
> the percentage of people suffering
> from the disorders. A preview function
> populates a dummy web page with your
> color scheme, which is a handy tool
> for seeing how your selected colors
> look together off the palette.
>
> While the page-simulator is a really
> great trick, the best feature of Color
> Scheme Designer is the ability to
> export your palette not just as a
> Photoshop palette—a common limitation
> of many web-based generators—but as
> HTML+CSS, XML, TXT, and GPL (the
> palette format for GIMP).

Comment: Color Scheme Designer is brilliant. It also has colourblindness features that have been really useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite: http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorwheel.asp

http://www.visibone.com/colorlab/

http://www.wellstyled.com/tools/colorscheme2/index-en.html

http://www.allprofitallfree.com/color-wheel2.html

Answer (score 3):

[ColorBlender](http://colorblender.com) or [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com)

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with davebug, Kuler (kuler.adobe.com) all the way!

Answer (score 1):

I love Adobe's www.kuler.com ... if you sign up, you can download the palettes as Adobe Swatch files and use them in Creative Suite products.

Though, it's really just a search tool for user-submitted palettes... maybe not exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is very good: http://www.gpeters.com/color/color-schemes.php.

All you have to do is to write a keyword and let Yahoo! to pick your color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Colr.org](http://www.colr.org/) a lot.  It doesn't have a color wheel, but it has some really interesting features.  You can choose a color scheme from an image, tag colors--and color schemes and even search on the tags.  It's good for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) for quite a while.  It's been excellent for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Colorotate](http://www.colorotate.org/) seems good too.